# upload data in background ios

Tags: ios

I know there are already some similar questions on stack overflow, but i am not clear from these.

I am working on taxi app. I want to send the coordinates of driver to server even app is in background. I am  able to send coordinates to server for 10 minutes but after 10 minutes it stops.

I have check the apple doc, there is written that location based apps can execute in background.

Can anybody help me how can i upload coordinates of driver to server in background?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sending current location to server in background as well as in running app using AFNetworking 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338466/sending-current-location-to-server-in-background-as-well-as-in-running-app-using)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the line:Project->Tagert->Capabilities->BackgroundModes,check right the item "Location updates"